# How to modify the service endpoint of an Azure Pipeline via API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to modify the service endpoint of a pipeline in Azure DevOps via API.

Example:

Pipeline "build-a-release" uses my personal service endpoint "hello1". But I want it to use existing service endpoint "my-companys-global-service-endpoint" instead.

The documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0 does not show any "update" function, but I can update the service endpoint of a pipeline in the Azure DevOps GUI.

How can I automate this process via a script and API?

[image: Change the service endpoint of a pipeline via the GUI]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update a service endpoint, you should use [Endpoints - Update Service Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/update%20service%20endpoint?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) API:

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/{endpointId}?api-version=6.0-preview.4
```

To update a pipeline defintion, you could use [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) api to update it. When you capture the network log, you could see there is `connectedServiceId` in `properties` of `repository` parameter. You could update the `connectedServiceId` to change the service connection.

From my test, something you need to notice:

1. Make sure the request headers include the following items:

[image]

2. Make sure you have the correct "revision" value (the latest revision) in the body.

Comment: Thank you; unfortunately, my question might be a bit ambiguous; I just noticed it and will try to fix it: I do not want to change a service endpoint by itself. I want to change the service endpoint attribute of a pipeline.

Comment: So you want to update a pipeline. If you use classical pipeline, you could use [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) api to update it. If you use YAML pipeline, you could use [Pushes - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#update-a-file) api to update the yaml file.

Comment: Do these apis help you?

Comment: Not entirely yet. The "pushes - create" api can change files, but not the service endpoint of the pipeline. I use a yaml pipeline, but want to change which service endpoint it uses to connect to github. The Definitions - Update API has a "BuildDefinition" object with a "repository" parameter of type "BuildRepository", so I potentially could update it. But the BuildRepository type does not have a "ServiceEndpoint" id. When I use the az cli to show all properties of the definition, it shows the service endpoint id. But how to change it?

Comment: So you meant the service connection your repo used. This information should be able to be updated in `Resources: repositories` in yaml file:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-repositories

Comment: Isn't that only for "If your pipeline has templates in another repository, or if you want to use multi-repo checkout with a repository that requires a service connection"? I want to change the primary service connection (service endpoint) of my pipeline. I have added a screenshot to the original question. We are still trying to do this via API... Now trying to reproduce the API calls the GUI triggers.

Comment: When you capture the network log, you could see there is `connectedServiceId` parameter in `properties` of `repository`in  [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) api. Check my updated reply.

Comment: Have you checked my updated reply? Is your issue solved?

Comment: Yes, you are right, this worked. Somehow, it was for us not possible to _only_ change this one parameter, and capturing the network log returned a quite huge json data for the push. But it turned out that we can use the GET method first to retrieve a json data object, then modify only the json_data['repository']['properties']['connectedServiceId'] value, and PUSH the modified json back to the server. This would solve the issue with the revision and ensure the json object contains all necessary data.